# Que problemas podem ocorrer ao usar a namespace "http://tempuri.org/" em nossos webServices?

Tags: asp.net, web-service, soap, namespace, xml-namespaces

Ao criar um webService, em meu caso usando ASP.NET, sempre mudo o namespace padrão para algum relacionado ao meu projeto, geralmente usando a URL do site para isso.

Mas ultimamente tenho tido a necessidade de integrar sistemas e geralmente outros desenvolvedores tem me enviado o namespace "http://tempuri.org", que para mim significa (URI temporária).

O ASP.NET inclusive alerta para isso, mas sei que alguns desenvolvedores simplesmente ignoram esse alerta.

Abaixo um exemplo do alerta, que diz :

> This web service is using http://tempuri.org/ as its default namespace.
>
> Recommendation: Change the default namespace before the XML Web service is made public.

```html
<html>

    <head><link rel="alternate" type="text/xml" href="/Clientes/IntegraBlueXCDCF.asmx?disco" />

    <style type="text/css">
    
  BODY { color: #000000; background-color: white; font-family: Verdana; margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 0px; }
  #content { margin-left: 30px; font-size: .70em; padding-bottom: 2em; }
  A:link { color: #336699; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline; }
  A:visited { color: #6699cc; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline; }
  A:active { color: #336699; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline; }
  A:hover { color: cc3300; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline; }
  P { color: #000000; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 12px; font-family: Verdana; }
  pre { background-color: #e5e5cc; padding: 5px; font-family: Courier New; font-size: x-small; margin-top: -5px; border: 1px #f0f0e0 solid; }
  td { color: #000000; font-family: Verdana; font-size: .7em; }
  h2 { font-size: 1.5em; font-weight: bold; margin-top: 25px; margin-bottom: 10px; border-top: 1px solid #003366; margin-left: -15px; color: #003366; }
  h3 { font-size: 1.1em; color: #000000; margin-left: -15px; margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px; }
  ul { margin-top: 10px; margin-left: 20px; }
  ol { margin-top: 10px; margin-left: 20px; }
  li { margin-top: 10px; color: #000000; }
  font.value { color: darkblue; font: bold; }
  font.key { color: darkgreen; font: bold; }
  font.error { color: darkred; font: bold; }
  .heading1 { color: #ffffff; font-family: Tahoma; font-size: 26px; font-weight: normal; background-color: #003366; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; margin-left: -30px; padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 3px; padding-left: 15px; width: 105%; }
  .button { background-color: #dcdcdc; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 1em; border-top: #cccccc 1px solid; border-bottom: #666666 1px solid; border-left: #cccccc 1px solid; border-right: #666666 1px solid; }
  .frmheader { color: #000000; background: #dcdcdc; font-family: Verdana; font-size: .7em; font-weight: normal; border-bottom: 1px solid #dcdcdc; padding-top: 2px; padding-bottom: 2px; }
  .frmtext { font-family: Verdana; font-size: .7em; margin-top: 8px; margin-bottom: 0px; margin-left: 32px; }
  .frmInput { font-family: Verdana; font-size: 1em; }
  .intro { margin-left: -15px; }
           
    </style>

    <title>
 Meu WebService
</title></head>

  <b>

    <div id="content">

      <p class="heading1">Meu WebService de Exemplo</p><br>

      <span>
          <p class="intro"><h2>Minha descrição do WebService</h2></p>
      </span>

      <span>

          <p class="intro">The following operations are supported.  For a formal definition, please review the <a href="MeuWebService.asmx?WSDL">Service Description</a>. </p>
          
          
              <ul>
            
              <li>
                <a href="MeuWebService.asmx?op=MeuMetodoExemplo">MeuMetodoExemplo</a>
                
                <span>
                  <br>Descrição do MeuMetodoExemplo.
                </span>
              </li>
              <p>
            
              </ul>
            
      </span>

      
      

    <span>
        
    </span>
    
      <span>
          <hr>
          <h3>This web service is using http://tempuri.org/ as its default namespace.</h3>
          <h3>Recommendation: Change the default namespace before the XML Web service is made public.</h3>
          <p class="intro">Each XML Web service needs a unique namespace in order for client applications to distinguish it from other services on the Web. http://tempuri.org/ is available for XML Web services that are under development, but published XML Web services should use a more permanent namespace.</p>
          <p class="intro">Your XML Web service should be identified by a namespace that you control. For example, you can use your company's Internet domain name as part of the namespace. Although many XML Web service namespaces look like URLs, they need not point to actual resources on the Web. (XML Web service namespaces are URIs.)</p>
          <p class="intro">For XML Web services creating using ASP.NET, the default namespace can be changed using the WebService attribute's Namespace property. The WebService attribute is an attribute applied to the class that contains the XML Web service methods. Below is a code example that sets the namespace to "http://microsoft.com/webservices/":</p>
          <p class="intro">C#</p>
          <pre>[WebService(Namespace="http://microsoft.com/webservices/")]
public class MyWebService {
    // implementation
}</pre>
          <p class="intro">Visual Basic</p>
          <pre>&lt;WebService(Namespace:="http://microsoft.com/webservices/")&gt; Public Class MyWebService
    ' implementation
End Class</pre>

          <p class="intro">C++</p>
          <pre>[WebService(Namespace="http://microsoft.com/webservices/")]
public ref class MyWebService {
    // implementation
};</pre>
          <p class="intro">For more details on XML namespaces, see the W3C recommendation on <a href="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/">Namespaces in XML</A>.</p>
          <p class="intro">For more details on WSDL, see the <a href="http://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl">WSDL Specification</a>.</p>
          <p class="intro">For more details on URIs, see <a href="http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt">RFC 2396</a>.</p>
      </span>

      

    
  </body>
</html>
```

Minha questão é: 
A namespace em nossos webServices é algo com que devo me preocupar? Posso ter problemas se tiver que consumir vários webServices com a mesma namespace?

Answer (score 5):

Existe uma [**recomendação**](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names) em que cada serviço precisa de um *namespace* exclusivo para que os aplicativos cliente possa distingui-lo de outros serviços na Web.

`http://tempuri.org` é o [**URI**](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI) padrão de teste usado por produtos de desenvolvimento da *Microsoft*, como o Visual Studio. Ele está disponível para *Web Services* que estão em desenvolvimento, mas *Web Services* publicados devem usar outro namespace, com URI mais significativo nos sistemas de produção.

Ou seja, enquanto você está desenvolvendo o Web Service é bom deixar como tempuri.org mas não se esqueça de mudar isso antes publica-lo.